# C++ Calling correct virtual method in mult

Tags: c++, plugins, multiple-inheritance

I'm writing some modular application and I'm trying to use abstract classess and (pure) virtual functions/methods like interfaces.

So I have defined some "interfaces":

```
class first { 
public: 
  virtual ~first() {}; 
  virtual void first_method() = 0;
};

class second { ... second_method() ... };
```

And class that implements these:

```
class TheObject : public BaseClass, public first, public second {
public: 
  void first_method();
  void second_method();
}

void TheObject::first_method() { do_something();} 
void TheObject::second_method() { do_something_better();}
```

Btw, BaseClass have some virtual (but not pure) methods too.

OK, now, when I do all the dlopen, dlsym etc, I'll try to pass TheObject (from TheObject) to plugin like this:

```
//In main app
pluginit(this);
// In plugin:
void pluginit (void * obj) {
    first * cls = (first*) obj;
    cls->first_method();  // FAIL!
}
```

At line with // FAIL!, program goes to some virtual method of BaseClass. I think I know why - in compile time plugin sees only "interface" first and don't know, that vtable consist more "interfaces".

The question is - how to correctly pass this interface to plugin, which don't know TheObject? Something like

```
new first : this; // typeof this = TheObject
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conversion to void pointer does not magically account for base classes. If you convert something to void pointer, all you can do with that is convert it back *to the type you had originally*.

So you need to do this:

```
derived * obj = new derived;
void * arg = static_cast<first *>(obj);      // upcast first!
f(arg);

// ... 

void f(void * p)
{
    first * obj = static_cast<first *>(p);   // all you know is that p
                                             // is a base pointer
    obj->foo();
}
```

Comment: @MikeS.: The annoying part here is that without multiple inheritance, you might never have noticed this error :-S